# Multilanguage site with Python Django

Tags: python, django

We are making a site for multiple users, using Python Django.

We need to set language of system messages (such as indications of user's errors, labels of control elements, etc.) different for different registered users.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Django has a very mature and standard internationalization framework. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/) is extensive and well organized.

Unless you want to avoid using Django's own facilities for translation, which could be the case for applications heavy in client-side code, this is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

There is `activate` function in `django.utils.translation`, to set the language for current session.